# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' on flask run

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I already installed tensorflow,

```
Python 3.7.7 (default, Apr 15 2020, 05:09:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2020-10-12 14:37:43.718059: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
```

So, I want to deploy my model using Flask. but when I do `flask run` I got this error:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mr777\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\Ngoding Python\Skripsi\deploy\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I've already uninstalled tensorflow and reinstalled it again. the issue still remains.
anyway I ran it on environment using Anaconda.

Comment: Where was tensorflow installed?

Comment: of course in that environment, I activated that environment so I got my first code like above, but in the same environment when I ```flask run``` it failed

Answer (score 0):

Create a conda venv by:

```
conda --create tensorflask python=3.7
```

in the conda terminal.

Activate it by:

```
conda activate
```

once that is activated

```
pip install tensorflow flask
```

then run your file by Cd'ing in and running it.

or

Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it again (Both Of These Worked For Me)

Comment: I installed tensorflow-gpu, does it make different?

Comment: @Ilham Do you have an NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: @Ilham I run on an Integrated GPU and I have installed ```pip install tensorflow-gpu``` and it works without errors

Comment: but I've feeling that because I have ```tensorflow-gpu``` makes my flask not recognized it

Comment: @Ilham Go to terminal CMD/PWRSHLL and type ```python```

Comment: ```import tensorlfow```

Comment: ```import flask```

Comment: And If One of them errors out , uninstall that and try to debug it

Comment: @Ilham could be

Answer (score 0):

So basically, in my current environment it's not installed flask yet, but I do can serve a server using flask too without tensorflow it worked. maybe anaconda just bugged and using base environment installed flask to run that server.

after I installed flask on my current environment it worked good. so basically it's a bug. whether by python/anaconda.